# listing functions and methods in VS code

Tags: c, function, visual-studio-code, symbols

I know that by clicking ctrl+shift+'o' one can get a list of all function symbol, but is there a way to get it in a text format? Something like that:

`string functions = getFunctions();`

*`print(functions)`*

`>>> ['int hello_world()', 'void foo()' ...]`

I don't really know how does this thing work, are these symbols a compiler's thing or IDE's, but I'm sure that the IDE 'knows' about them and therefore can tell me...

Comment: write an extension, call `vscode.executeDocumentSymbolProvider` and insert the symbol names of the result in a new editor file

Comment: Is this along the lines of what you want https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432250/199224? Or https://ctags.io/.